# JSF CDI : Conversation scope bean[s] best practice

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm currently learning about JSF 2.0 and im so glad for the existence of this conversation scope feature, which is very helpful in opening a new tab or a new window on the same page and having separate resources, not overriding one another.

But im curious on how to implement this in a good way, about when to start the conversation and when to close it.

In my case, i have each CDI bean for each JSF page. And let's say that i have a menu, and when it's clicked, this will lead to page A, and from A, could lead to B, B could lead to C, C could lead to D, all these 4 pages are connected in one chain.

Accessing A's bean properties from B or C or D beans is possible, accessing B's properties is also possible from C or D beans and so forth.

Now im quite confused about :

- whether all these A B C D should be
  in conversation scope or not, or
  perhaps just A ? Because i think
  sometimes from another page that is
  outside the ABCD chain, like a page
  F, it could navigate to page B,
  although i dont know how to supply
  the data to the bean B  yet.
- whether all these A B C D should be
  combined into one bean
- where and when to start the
  conversation, im thinking about the
  constructor, but i dont think it's a
  good idea, because i prefer starting
  the conversation when first accessing
  the page, not the bean
- where and when to stop the
  conversation, so that there wont be
  unused resources hanging around

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: CDI is not part of standard JSF. CDI stands for Contexts and Dependency Injection (JSR-299) which covers the annotations of  `javax.enterprise` package. Conversation Scope is also not part of standard JSF. It was an JBoss Seam invention during JSF 1.2 ages and has been adopted by JSF 2.0 specification as View Scope, togglable by `@ViewScoped` annotation. Now, what are you actually talking about?

Comment: Hello BalusC, thanks for the clarification. I used the term CDI just to make clear what i'm using, but maybe that information is unrelated to my question, my apology :) As far as i know, the @ViewScoped is for a single page getting redisplayed and the properties will be persisted. But what i wanted to achieve from conversation scope is that i can open the same page on several tabs, with each tab as if having it's own session scope. So submitting the value 'albert' on a myBean.name on a tab wont override the myBean.name on other tabs. But im confused on where to start and end the conversation.

Comment: And this gets more confusing for me if there are 4 pages, for example, page A is a browse page, where user can search, page B is the detail page, where user can modify details, page C is where user can modify sub detail, and so forth. If i wanted to be able to open page A in several tabs without one affecting another, i have to use conversation scope on A's bean. But i suppose it's gonna be conversation scope too for B C and D ? Also about where and when should i begin / end the conversation. I mean, user can open new tabs, and close the tabs. How can i detect this and close the conversation ?

Comment: Albert, when replying to comments in posts which are not the commenter's own, use `@nickname` like `@BalusC` to get them automatically notified about the comment-reply. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSF 2 provides Request, View, Session, and Application scopes.  CDI introduces the Conversation scope, but more importantly, it introduces a standard by which new scopes can be added to the platform.

The Scope you are describing is probably better suited by a custom scope like a window scope.  Two projects implementing this scope are:

1. [Apache MyFaces CODI](https://cwiki.apache.org/EXTCDI/conversations.html)
2. IceFaces has a JSF (non-CDI) [Window scope implementation](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/ICEfaces+1.x+Compatibility#ICEfaces1.xCompatibility-scopes).

Nevertheless, I would encourage you to rethink your bean structure.  I've become quite fond of the View scope myself, coupled with the JSF 2 view parameters to propagate information from one page to another (and from one View scope instance to another).

MyFaces "View Access" scope seems like another neat approach, where a bean stays in scope so long as the pages you navigate through maintain a reference to that scope.

Comment: Thank you ! I've been thinking about View scope also, and it could be used in multitab or multiwindow environment too. What you meant by passing view parameters from one viewscope to another viewscope, is that the one achieved from h:button and nested f:param, and with the f:metadata with nested f:viewParam, am i correct ? If im not mistaken, the h:button will result in GET request, and this pose a problem to me, since sometimes, for example, pressing delete from page B (POST) would return the navigation to page A. Is there a way to send view param from B to A in this case ?

Comment: You can append the string "?includeViewParams=true" to a navigation rule, and the view params defined on the "landing page" will automatically be included for you.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Read about this once, but never thought of using it before. I think i got used to session scope where everything is where it is. Gotta try this out :)

Comment: CDI does not have @ViewScoped implemented, do you have a preference between CODI and Seam3?

Comment: Given that I'm the Seam 3 Faces Module lead, I do have a (somewhat biased) preference ;)

Look at what else the two projects offer, and choose what's best aligned with your needs.